# How to separate html for header/footer?

Tags: php, html, header, footer

I want to generate header and footer sections for my web app.

include header;
header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>

<!-- My content here from the rest of the application  -->
```

include footer;
footer:

```
  </body>
</html>
```

This way suits me well since i can simply include all i need by just including both files in every page. I feel that it's a bad practice though. Can I do it this way? How do I do it the right way?

Comment: "i can simply include all i need by just including both files in every page" — This is fine, and ideal for many types of web application.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, or another dynamic content scripting language, simply make another file with functions to return header/footer HTML, then call it from your original page. Otherwise, you can use the `<header>` and `<footer>` tags inside the `<body>` to separate content.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common to have separate header and footer files, like you propose, with inner content as separate files:

[image: Page Template Structure]

However, I think it's better to structure it in a nested way where you have an outer template that contains your header/footer, and inner templates/content also structured in a nested way.

[image: Nested Template Structure]

This makes your templates much more manageable and maintainable down the road.  It's far better to have your opening/closing tags in the same file.  You can preview them as you develop those templates.  You avoid creating invalid HTML because you can easily see the opening/closing tags in the same place.  It reduces the overall files you're managing.

Additionally, as you're using PHP, I recommend using the [Smarty Template Engine](https://www.smarty.net/).  It helps you with common templating needs, like escaping content in different contexts, or making reusable components.

Answer (score 0):

Write the header in a file eg `header.php`, in another file, eg `footer.php`, write the footer and then in the last file write your application and use `include("header.php");` and `include("footer.php");`to include your files in place